# Display javascript in 2 id's

Tags: javascript

I have this countdown:

```
function startTimer2(duration, display) {
var timer2 = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes2 = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds2 = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes2 : minutes2 + "m ";
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds2 : seconds2 + "sek ";

    display.textContent = minutes + "" + seconds;
    if (--timer2 < 0) {
        timer2 = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes2 = 60 * 60,
        display2 = document.querySelector("#time2");
    startTimer2(fiveMinutes2, display2);
};
```

and this html:

```
<p id="time1"></p>
<p id="time2"></p>
```

I want the time to display in both time1 and time2 - how can i do this?

Comment: the same way you do 1, but with an extra argument (display2 perhaps) for the other element, and  `display.textContent = display2.textContent = ... etc`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a second parameter to `startTime2`, or pass in an array of elements and loop over the array.

Second parameter:

```js
function startTimer2(duration, display1, display2) {
var timer2 = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes2 = parseInt(timer2 / 60, 10);
    seconds2 = parseInt(timer2 % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes2 : minutes2 + "m ";
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds2 : seconds2 + "sek ";

    display1.textContent = minutes + "" + seconds;
    display2.textContent = minutes + "" + seconds;
    if (--timer2 < 0) {
        timer2 = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes2 = 60 * 60,
        display1 = document.querySelector("#time1"),
        display2 = document.querySelector("#time2");
    startTimer2(fiveMinutes2, display1, display2);
};
```

```html
<p id="time1"></p>
<p id="time2"></p>
```

Using an array:

```js
function startTimer2(duration, display) {
var timer2 = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes2 = parseInt(timer2 / 60, 10);
    seconds2 = parseInt(timer2 % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes2 : minutes2 + "m ";
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds2 : seconds2 + "sek ";

    for (var i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {    
      display[i].textContent = minutes + "" + seconds;
    }

    if (--timer2 < 0) {
        timer2 = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes2 = 60 * 60
        , displayElems = [];
    
    displayElems[0] = document.querySelector("#time1");
    displayElems[1] = document.querySelector("#time2");
    
    startTimer2(fiveMinutes2, displayElems);
};
```

```html
<p id="time1"></p>
<p id="time2"></p>
```

Comment: Alternatively use `push` to add to the array: `displayElems.push(document.getElementById("#time1")); displayElems.push(document.querySelector("#time2"));`. Also, `document.getElementById` is what I'd favour over using `querySelector` in this case. It is a faster operation.